# How do I fix my UI Buttons not working in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on an Inventory system in unity and have the icons as image panels with a button attached as a child for functionality, and this is used in a prefab. But, when I click the button, the attached EventListener does not run, and when I changed the highlight colors to be visible, I found out the button was not even registering a click. More surprising was that the button and the eventListener worked perfectly before, and undoing my changes did not solve the issue.

I tried playing around with the script, but I couldn't find the problem and since no errors popped up, I couldn't try much. The button still does not work. I have attached the inspector screen.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Some other UI element may be blocking button.
- Be sure that Canvas has `GraphicRaycaster` component. Without it, you cannot interact with UI elements.

Comment: there was a panel blocking it. Thanks a lot for the help!